# How do I use the current instance of a class?

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following classes:-

`Common`: contains common methods

`Tab`: represents a single tab in a browser

`Window`: represents the browser window

```
Class Common
{
   public goURL()
   {
       //method definition
   }
}

Class Tab 
{
   int tab_id;
   string tab_name;
   Common common;

   public Tab(tab_id, tab_name)
   {
      this.tab_id = tab_id;
      this.tab_name = tab_name; 
      common = new Common();
   }

   public void createNewTab()
   {
      //method definition
      this.common.goURL(); 
   }
}

Class Window
{
   public void startWindow()
   {
     //how do I access goURL() here using current instance of Tab?
   }
   public void newTabButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Tab T0 = new Tab(0, "Tab Zero");
      T0.createNewTab();
   }
}
```

How do I access the `goURL()` method using the `common` field inside an instance of `Tab` class?

One option is to make the method static and access it without creating an object.

**EDIT:**

This was bad Object-Oriented design from my end.
I ended up following the programming principles of *High Cohesion* and *Loose Coupling* to re-design my classes and come up with a better design.
Thanks to everyone for the advice!

Comment: My guess is that `goURL` could be static if that class doesn't have any fields.  In fact based on what you're showing `Common` could be static as well.

Comment: Are you trying to access common.goUrl() from the Window class?

Comment: @juharr The `Common` class does have a field.

Comment: @SamGoldberg I am trying to access it like this: `current_instance_of_tab.common.goURL()`

Comment: @Arjun: Set `Common` to `public` inside `Tab` then.

Comment: Is the field used in `goURL`?  If so it cannot be static and you just need to make it accessible using the appropriate access modifier (public or internal).

Comment: I have no idea what your startWindow method should be doing? Does it create a new window for browser? Is it initalizing something on existing window? Should it create a new window with a new tab and navigate to some specific url by default?

Comment: @Arjun: OO design principles say that you shouldn't, in general, be calling methods on objects contained within other objects.  See [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).  This principle makes your code more flexible and creates less dependencies between objects.  So a better approach would be to add a new `public` method to Tab, which allows client objects to call the `goURL()` method.  If you don't follow good design principles, you end up with a system where everything is `static` or `public`, making it a "brittle" system.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen I just abstracted everything for the sake of the question. But, `goURL()` actually fetches the web response. `Common` actually has a field which I instantiate in its constructor. This field is used in the definition of `goURL()` to achieve another task.

Comment: Thank you @SamGoldberg. I completely understand what you are saying. The current OO design was bad so I took your advice and re-designed my classes to make it more modular. This allowed me to dissect the problem and come up with a working solution!